# Retrieve file by ID Silverstripe

Tags: php, image, file, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am currently using  SilverStripe 4.1 and I am trying to retrieve an image from the database and it always returns `null`.

When I go to the database I see the file reference in the `File` table. Here is the `File` table content for the file I was trying to retrieve:

```
ID          | 2583
ClassName   | SilverStripe\Assets\Image
LastEdited  | 2018-11-08 21:05:48
Created     | 2018-11-08 21:05:48
Name        | logo-v5.png
Title       | logo-v5
ShowInSearch| 1
CanViewType | Inherit
CanEditType | Inherit
Version     | 1
ParentID    | 1753
OwnerID     | 10
FileHash    | 9e6faa29b752294d2e623bd83b17660df123af62
FileFilename| images/logo-v5.png
FileVariant | NULL
```

Here are the way I tried:

```
File::get()->byID(2583); 
Image::get()->byID(2583);  
File::get_by_id('SilverStripe\Assets\Image', 2583);
```

In all cases is returning `null`. Do you know what I am missing here?

Comment: bit of a guess, but is this something to do with publishing? i.e. do you need to publish it first as it is versioned?  alternatively can you do `$file = File::get()->filter('Name', 'logo-v5.png')->first();`?

Comment: Does the file exist? Is it published? Can you see it in the assets section of the admin area?